# What scale does contain these notes?? E, F#,G,A,B,C,D

Tags: piano, scales

As I was going to compose a song I wanted to know what scale contains these notes?
E,F#,G,A,B,C,D.

Comment: This shows no research by the OP.

Comment: Hi Shashank. As you can see from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signature#Scales_with_sharp_key_signatures, this *could* be G major, or E minor - but do you hear G as the 'home note', or E, or something else?

Answer (score 4):

The way the scale is written in the question (with E as the first and therefore lowest note) suggests that the note E is the tonic note. If this is the case, then **E minor** is the key described by those notes. This could also be described as E Aeolian, which would be its modal name, although E minor is the practical answer in most circumstances.

The way this question is phrased suggests that aurally identifying the tonic note may need explanation:

- The tonic note of a scale is the note that the other notes revolve around, the note that feels the most like "home" or acts as the center.
- If you can identify seven notes within the music as the question has already done but don't know the key, try playing the notes up and down the scale until you find one note that your brain thinks the others are leading towards.
- That note is what we name scales and keys by. So if E is the tonic note, then we can only be in a key or scale named "E something". In this case, the other notes form the pattern that makes up E *minor*.
- It will take practice to get a feel for things like the tonic and key and scale aurally. This is one of the difficulties of ear-training: the brain must learn to identify things that it is not used to paying attention to (and when I say "ear" I really mean "brain" - ear-training is actually brain-training, so you'll need to study!).
- I highly recommend practicing this sort of exercise with a musician who is more experienced than oneself, so that they can work through issues with you and isolate the thing that you are listening for.

Now, it is possible that within certain contexts those same seven notes could describe other scales or keys. For example, when you play all the white notes on a piano starting on C, you've played the C major scale. Play them all starting and ending with A, though, and you should be able to hear it as the key of A minor instead. *(In fact, if you want to get a bit more technical, there are seven modes within the Ionian modal family, and Aeolian is just one of them!)* In this way, **it is also possible that E is not the tonic.** Perhaps the notes are better described as **G major**? Note that in music, starting a scale on a certain note doesn't always mean that the note is the tonic, but it does tend to help the ear identify it as such.

---

The concepts of major, minor, keys, and scales are not specific to songwriting or composition. Rather, these are some general and fundamental music theory structures. They can be useful when applied to songwriting and composition, but without a basic understanding of what these concepts are, it is easy to get bogged down in theory terms and lose sight of how to make music. It will do you no good to know that your music is in E minor if you do not really know what E minor is!

Answer (score 1):

it would technically be E aeolian

Comment: ...or G Ionian...or F#Locrian...or A Dorian...or...

Comment: E minor is just as 'technical' :-)